# How to calculate SUM with filter using DAX?

Tags: filter, powerbi, sum, dax, wildcard

I am going to calculate the sum of a column by filtering it first.
I did this way

```
Total = SUMX(FILTER('Backlog items', 'Backlog items'[Name]="*Student*"),[Score])
```

I need to calculate the sum of `[Score]` when the `[Name]` contains of `Student`, but the result is still empty, because it can't catch the filter.

Anyone can help me to have an idea about it?
Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CONTAINSSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/containsstring-function-dax) function, for example like this:

```
Total = SUMX(
    FILTER('Backlog items', 
        CONTAINSSTRING('Backlog items'[Name], "Student")
    ), [Score])
```